# Service worker and Django

Tags: javascript, django

I create a project in Django and I want add a service worker that will be redirect to another page (normal html without django tags )  in the absence of a connection. 
How can i do this?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Open the source code of your HTML web page. And copy it in a file inside your static folder.

Make sure you have STATIC_URL in your settings.py enabled and is available through the address.

Then in your service-worker.js add:

```
var filesToCache = ['desired_HTML_page.html']
```

Afterwards make the corresponding install and fetch events.